# Electron production binaries only partially loads front app

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Electron binaries doesn't behave like dev as only a "partial" load of the front seems to happen:

I'm using React, electron-vite and electron-builder for Windows binaries.

Dev:
[image]

App.exe:
[image]
(what are those Expression  console logs?)

electron.vite.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig({
  main: {
    build: {
      watch: {
        include: 'src\\main\\**',
        chokidar: {
          usePolling: true
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: [externalizeDepsPlugin(), 
      viteStaticCopy({
        targets: [
          {
            src: normalizePath(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets' + '/**')),
            dest: 'assets'
          }
        ]
      }),]
  },
  preload: {
    plugins: [externalizeDepsPlugin()]
  },
  renderer: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@renderer': resolve('src/renderer/src')
      }
    },
    plugins: [react()]
  },
})
```

electron-builder.yml:

```
appId: com.stelifill.app
productName: Stellifill
directories:
  buildResources: build
files:
  - '!**/.vscode/*'
  - 'out/**/*'
  - '!electron.vite.config.{js,ts,mjs,cjs}'
  - '!{.eslintignore,.eslintrc.cjs,.prettierignore,.prettierrc.yaml,dev-app-update.yml,CHANGELOG.md,README.md}'
  - '!{.env,.env.*,.npmrc,pnpm-lock.yaml}'
  - '!{tsconfig.json,tsconfig.node.json,tsconfig.web.json}'
compression: normal
asarUnpack:
  - resources/**
# afterSign: build/notarize.js
win:
  executableName: Stellifill
nsis:
  artifactName: ${name}-${version}-setup.${ext}
  shortcutName: ${productName}
  uninstallDisplayName: ${productName}
  createDesktopShortcut: always
mac:
  entitlementsInherit: build/entitlements.mac.plist
  extendInfo:
    - NSCameraUsageDescription: Application requests access to the device's camera.
    - NSMicrophoneUsageDescription: Application requests access to the device's microphone.
    - NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription: Application requests access to the user's Documents folder.
    - NSDownloadsFolderUsageDescription: Application requests access to the user's Downloads folder.
dmg:
  artifactName: ${name}-${version}.${ext}
linux:
  target:
    - AppImage
    - snap
    - deb
  maintainer: electronjs.org
  category: Utility
appImage:
  artifactName: ${name}-${version}.${ext}
npmRebuild: false
publish:
  provider: generic
  url: https://example.com/auto-updates
```

I can't figure out what's wrong here, any help would be appreciated.